# Get document path in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, path

Hi i want to get **path** of document, I want to use **`jfilechooser`** but **`jfilechooser`** get file path, but i want document **path**, what can i do ?

Comment: Please, be concrete. You have a `JTextPane`? And you wanna get the path of the document which is being displayed, right?

Comment: Do you mean directory/folder?

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus I love your username. I really do.

Comment: can you tell us what the file path is that jfilechooser is giving you, and what the document path is you want?

Comment: @jmendeth lol my invention of it is one of my proudest accomplishments ;)

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus so is the symbol for your name: +++ ?

Comment: yes i want to get document path(directory/folder), i want to select document with swing ,like jfilechooser, sorry for my English ...

Comment: @mcalex It really depends on your religious/lack of religiousness standpoint.

Answer (score 3):

You really should have googled this first. That was all I did in order to find this:

```
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
```

Then run the file chooser, and use this to get the directory location.

```
String dir = chooser.getCurrentDirectory();
```

You could have found this on Google. Next time, look around on for at least 15 minutes before asking your question here.

Comment: @brano88 It was a LMGTFY question.

Comment: Agree...thats why he got 3 downvotes...if you know what I mean. :)